# Typeset one citation with all authors

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I'm using the `authoryear` style in `biblatex` with the following options name length options:

```
maxcitenames=1, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=999, minbibnames=999
```

So citations (usually issued with `\cite`) are properly typeset with only one author like

> Shakespeare et al, The...

However I want to typeset a single citation (via `\fullcite`) with all authors listed, eg.

> W. Shakespeare, J. Austen and D. Adams, The...

How can I *temporarily* increase the values of `maxcitenames` and `mincitenames`? Or is there another way to typeset only the `\fullcite` citatation with all names?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to be able to make full use of all of `biblatex`'s features for `\fullcite`, namely pre- and postnotes, you might want to try this version.

We temporarily set `maxcitenames` to `maxbibnames`; apparently, there is no need to re-set the counter, because everything is wrapped in a group, so the assignment is locally.

A simpler solution than the below wrapper is

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\longfullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\c@maxnames\blx@maxbibnames\relax
      \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
```

---

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tempmaxup}[1]{\def\blx@maxcitenames{\blx@maxbibnames}#1}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\longfullcite}[\tempmaxup]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Unfortunately, I have found no better way of doing this than via that wrapper command.

The MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Reference:1994,
  author           =  {First I. Last and Second Y. Author and Third Z. Author and Fourth Q. Author},
  title            = {This is the article title},
  journal          = {T Journal T},
  journallongtitle = {The Journal Title},
  year             = 1994,
  volume           = 50,
  number           = 6,
  pages            = {30--40},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tempmaxup}[1]{\def\blx@maxcitenames{\blx@maxbibnames}#1}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\longfullcite}[\tempmaxup]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l p{8cm} }
  \verb|\autocite| & \autocite{Reference:1994}\\
  \verb|\longfullcite| &\longfullcite{Reference:1994}\\
  \verb|\longfullcite| & \longfullcite[see][14]{Reference:1994}\\
  \verb|\fullcite| & \fullcite{Reference:1994}\\
  \verb|\autocite| &\autocite{Reference:1994}\\
\end{tabular}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
% end of file comment
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Nice.  Why does `\tmpmaxup` have to be defined as taking an argument?

Comment: @AlanMunn Well, I could not get the redefinition of the counter to work in the pre- or post-code fields, so it had to be the wrapper command. The wrapper command must take one argument, which is the citation. (That is, if you take `\mkbibparens` as wrapper, the `\cite` command will we wrapped in parentheses.)

Comment: Ok.  That makes a bit more sense now.  I hadn't thought of the analogy to `\mkbibparens`. (I also tried to put the redefinition in the pre-code without success.)

Comment: +1. Very nice solution. I've tried it and it works as advertised.

Comment: @moewe: I am having trouble using your `\longfullcite` command with certain Biber/BibTeX entries.  The problem is too complicated to describe in a comment so I've opened [a separate question for it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350793/22603).

Answer (score 25):

To change `maxnames` for one citation only you may use the counter:

```
\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}\fullcite{Reference:1994}
```

This sets both `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames` but in your case this is not probably the problem. Unfortunately there is no `maxcitenames` counter in `biblatex`.

You may also define a dedicated command for such citations:

```
\newcommand{\longfullcite}{%
  \AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}%
  \fullcite}
```

Comment: +1 It seems that it will take me longer to learn `biblatex` than it did to learn LaTeX.

Comment: I adore `biblatex` for the things like this :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a kind of hacky way to do this.  Because of the complexity of the arguments of the `\cite` commands, it's not easy to wrap code around them.  So the following solution assumes that you will just use `\fullcite` with a single argument and none of its optional arguments.  I'd be interested in seeing a more elegant way to do this.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Reference:1994,
  author =   {First I. Last and Second Y. Author and Third Z. Author and Fourth Q. Author },
  title =    {This is the article title},
  journal =  {T Journal T},
  journallongtitle =     {The Journal Title},
  year =     1994,
  volume =   50,
  number = 6,
  pages =    {30--40}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=1, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=999,
     minbibnames=999]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\upmax}{\def\blx@maxcitenames{99}}
\newcommand{\dnmax}{\def\blx@maxcitenames{1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\myfullcite[1]{\upmax\fullcite{#1}\dnmax} % does not allow pre or postnotes

\begin{document}
\autocite{Reference:1994}

\myfullcite{Reference:1994}

\autocite{Reference:1994}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]