# Typesetting a full citation whose title ends with a word in braces

Tags: biblatex

I am using Biblatex and need to typeset full citations in my document text, so I'm using [moewe's `\longfullcite` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142153/22603).  While it works correctly most of the time, it has trouble with Biber/BibTeX entries where the last word of a field is enclosed in braces (to force capitalization).  In these cases, `\longfullcite` may fail to properly capitalize the following word.  Take the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tempmaxup}[1]{\def\blx@maxcitenames{\blx@maxbibnames}#1}
\makeatother
\DeclareCiteCommand{\longfullcite}[\tempmaxup]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@inproceedings{blow2015,
  author       = {Blow, Joe},
  title        = {{GNU} loves me},
  year         = 2015,
  booktitle    = {Proceedings of Some Conference},
}

@inproceedings{blow2016,
  author       = {Blow, Joe},
  title        = {I love {GNU}},
  year         = 2016,
  booktitle    = {Proceedings of Some Conference},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\noindent
\longfullcite{blow2015}\\
\longfullcite{blow2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: output of the above document, showing that the first \longfullcite correctly capitalizes "In" but the second one does not]

Note the inconsistent capitalization of the word "In" produced by the two `\longfullcite` commands.  By contrast, the citations emitted by `\printbibliography` correctly capitalize "In" for both entries.

What is causing this inconsistency and how can I fix or work around it (preferably by changing the definition of `\longfullcite` rather than changing the `.bib` file)?

Comment: You get the same problem with the standard \fullcite. And you also get it if you write GNU at the end without braces.  Capital letters have a different spacefactor and so can confuse the punctuation tracker. The correct  input is imho `title = {I love {GNU\@}}` (with or without braces). But you could also make a bug report at the biblatex tracker https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues. Perhaps the behaviour can be changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known problem (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/295) and affects all in-text citations, although it is probably only ever really visible with something `\fullcite`-like. Unfortunately, the chances for a proper solution are quite slim. `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker heavily modifies existing spacefactors, but doing so in citations can have unwanted knock-on effects for text outside citations.

You would have to add an `\@` after capital letters in the end of a title. But you can have that done automatically for you in the format, if you like

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\@}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot\@}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {title}{#1\@}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Dirty hack:**

Insert something invisible with no width. I am sure this can cause problems, I just don't know yet which problems :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tempmaxup}[1]{\def\blx@maxcitenames{\blx@maxbibnames}#1}
\makeatother
\DeclareCiteCommand{\longfullcite}[\tempmaxup]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@inproceedings{blow2015,
  author       = {Blow, Joe},
  title        = {{GNU} loves me},
  year         = 2015,
  booktitle    = {Proceedings of Some Conference},
}

@inproceedings{blow2016,
  author       = {Blow, Joe},
  title        = {I love {GNU}\mbox{}},
  year         = 2016,
  booktitle    = {Proceedings of Some Conference},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\noindent
\longfullcite{blow2015}\\
\longfullcite{blow2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: a `\strut` might do as well as an empty `\mbox`.  still a dirty hack.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your suggestion. However `\strut` seems not to work in this situation, the `i` is still lowercase.

Comment: The problem with a workaround involving the BibTeX file is that such files aren't always changeable (sometimes they're read in from a shared, read-only filesystem; sometimes you're typesetting in batch from user-generated content).