# \bibstring{in} changes case in a strange way, is this a bug?

Tags: biblatex, debugging

I've found some odd behavior of `\bibstring{in}`.  In this example, the first "in" ("in: *Procedia Computer Science*") is *lower case*, and the second is upper case ("In: *Houston J. Math*").

[image]

This behavior is not desired, and I have found a way to turn it off.  However, the MWE reveals what seems to my mind to be a bug in `\bibstring{in}`.  My guess is that the case changes because the last word in the first title is all-caps ("STEM").  But I could be wrong and am not sure where to find the defined behavior of `\bibstring{in}`.  I have pointedo out a workaround (insist on using capitalized verision all the time).

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{biblatex}
% \renewbibmacro{in:}{\printtext{In\intitlepunct}}  %% Uncomment this line to fix
% \renewbibmacro{in:}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}  %% this line doesn't work
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@article{Kohlhase2011598,
title={The {P}lanetary {S}ystem: {W}eb 3.0 \& {A}ctive {D}ocuments for {S}{T}{E}{M}},
journal={Procedia Computer Science},
volume={4},
pages={598--607},
year={2011},
note={Proceedings of the International Conference on Computational Science, ICCS 2011},
issn={1877-0509},
url={http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050911001219},
author={Kohlhase, M. and Corneli, J. and David, C. and Ginev, D. and Jucovschi, C. and Kohlhase, A. and Lange, C. and Matican, B. and Mirea, S. and Zholudev, V.},
addendum = {{\textbf{CORE: A}}; {\textbf{Google Scholar citations: 46}}},
}

@article{corneli2008double,
title={Double bubbles in Gauss space and spheres},
author={Corneli, Joe and Corwin, Ivan and Hurder, Stephanie and Sesum, Vojislav and Xu, Ya and Adams, Elizabeth and Davis, Diana and Lee, Michelle and Visocchi, R and Hoffman, Neil},
journal={Houston J. Math},
volume={34},
number={1},
pages={181--204},
year={2008},
url={http://www.math.brown.edu/~diana/math/DoubleBubbles.pdf},
addendum = {{\textbf{Google Scholar citations: 16}}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \fullcite{Kohlhase2011598}
\item \fullcite{corneli2008double}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

## To sum up

I'm surprised that `\bibstring{in}` would change case depending on surrounding context.  Is this a bug?

Comment: It's the punctuation tracker, I presume. You can probably 'fix' (or work around) the problem by writing `\@` after `STEM`: that is, `...{S}{T}{E}{M}\@},`.  (Note also that it's probably better, kerning-wise, to write `{Planetary}` rather than `{P}lanetary` (and for the other words).

Comment: This is a known problem, see the recent [Typesetting a full citation whose title ends with a word in braces](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350793/35864) as well as the relevant bug report [#259](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/295).

Comment: It's interesting that this problem comes up twice in so short a time, I can't remember having seen this issue on this site before. Note that the troubles only occur if you use citations, if you are in the bibliography, the punctuation tracker can use a set-up routine that prevents this from happening.