# Biblatex/Biber equivalent to cite all authors \cite*

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, biber

I would like to know what is in Biblatex/Biber the equivalent of `\cite*` that in natbib with Bibtex cites **all the authors** in the text.
In Biblatex it just displays the year or the title depending if one uses `author-year` or `author-title`, according to the [documentation](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).
In said documentation, there doesn't seem to be such a command.

Here is the specific style I use if it helps:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,maxbibnames=10,giveninits=true,natbib=true,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,dashed=false,uniquelist=false,uniquename=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142153/124842

Comment: I had found this answer and `\fullcite` does not work here, since it cites the title too, and the journal, etc. which I don't want. I would like a replica of what `\cite*` does: just cite all authors in the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change maxnames locally:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,
             maxbibnames=10,giveninits=true,natbib=true,doi=false,url=false,
             isbn=false,dashed=false,uniquelist=false,uniquename=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}             



\begin{document}

\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}\cite{herrmann}

\cite{herrmann}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

If you need it often you can define a cite command which does it, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,
             maxbibnames=10,giveninits=true,natbib=true,doi=false,url=false,
             isbn=false,dashed=false,uniquelist=false,uniquename=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}             

\DeclareCiteCommand{\longcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

\longcite{herrmann}

\cite{herrmann}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works indeed as a temporary solution! Any idea on how to use this to define a new command? (even better if it's `\cite*` since then I can change from Bibtex to Biblatex/Biber almost seamlessly)

Comment: I added an example (I simply copied the cite definition from authoryear.cbx). You could redefine \cite* but in biblatex it already has a meaning.

Comment: It works indeed! Any idea on how to have parenthesis around the year? (like in `\citet`?, this is what `\cite*`does)

Comment: ok I found my answer: replace `\usebibmacro{cite}` by `\usebibmacro{textcite}`

Comment: Note that the `natbib` compatibility mode uses `\AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}}}` Your first example will fail with `\parencite`. See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/354

Answer (score 0):

In biblatex you must use `\nocite{*}` to print all references

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking in the text, how to have all authors displayed, not in the bibliography