# Cite one time full name + year with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, xetex, citing, biber

My `biblatex` options look like this

```
\usepackage[
style=authoryear,       % author-year style in references
citestyle=authoryear-icomp, % compact author-year in cites
url=false,                   % clicable urls in ref.
uniquelist=false,
uniquename=false, % turn off auto-disambiguaty
backref=true,               % auto backrefs in ref.
datezeros=true,         % dates with leading zeros
maxcitenames=1, % et al. with two or more authors
%indexing,                   % to create an index of persons
sortcites=false,
sorting=nyt,
%defernumbers=true,     % numbers in any bibliography
backend=biber]              % use biber for compiling
{biblatex}
```

How can I cite one time only in the text full author names and year, like

*Gladwell, Malcolm, John Doe and John Smith (2005)?*

```
@book{Gladwell2005,
    author = {Gladwell, Malcolm and Doe, John and Smith, John},
    address = {New York, NY},
    publisher = {Back Bay Books},
    title = {Blink: The Power of Thinking Without Thinking},
    year = {2005},
}
```

All the other solutions given on `LaTeX stack exchange` have not helped me.

Comment: When you say 'one time', do you meant that you want the *first* citation in this format, or do you want a new command that you can use at will?

Comment: `style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear-icomp` is the same as `style=authoryear-icomp`. Both settings will automatically set `sorting=nyt`, so you don't need to do that yourself. `sortcite=false` is a somewhat bad idea with `style=authoryear-icomp`, you lose some of the compressing features.

Comment: I meant just once in the text (somewhere I determine). Not first citation. Thank you for the option input. I activated `sortcites=false`, because I want the cites in the text chronological, so `(Joe 2015; Smith 2016)`, not `(Smith 2016; Joe 2015)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new command for that `\extcite`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\extcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \begingroup
     \defcounter{maxnames}{999}%
     \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}%
     \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \endgroup}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

Alternatively, it is enough to just do

```
\AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}}}
```

right before the citation you want to change. You can of course wrap this into a command:

```
\newcommand*{\extendnextcite}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \AtEachCitekey{%
       \defcounter{maxnames}{999}%
       \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}}}}
```

and then use that as

```
\extendnextcite\cite{sigfridsson}
```

Comment: See also [Typeset one citation with all authors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142148/35864) for one part of this answer.