# Per-section bibliography styling using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm using

```
bibstyle=alphabetic,
maxnames=3,.
minnames=2,
maxalphanames=1,
```

In one section, I have some citations I wish to `\fullcite`. For these, I'd like to have *every* author listed (annoyingly, they contain between 4 and 9 authors). If I set `maxnames` higher, `\citet` makes the in-text citation difficult to read in the rest of the document.

Can I set `maxnames` for a specific section of the document, then change it back later?

---

Here's a MWE, showing the `\fullcite` that does *not* list all author names. In this example, the behaviour of `\citet` is good, but I want to increase `maxnames` as indicated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A+04,
  author = {Author, Aa and Buthor, Bb and Cuthor, Cc and Duthor, Dd},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal title},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {101--109},
  month = jan,
  note = {This is an article entry},
}
@article{A+02,
  author = {Author, Aa and Buthor, Bb},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal title},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {101--109},
  month = jan,
  note = {This is an article entry},
}
@article{A+03,
  author = {Author, Aa and Buthor, Bb and Cuthor, Cc},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal title},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {101--109},
  month = jan,
  note = {This is an article entry},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[bibstyle=alphabetic,maxnames=3,minnames=2,maxalphanames=1,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Fullcite}
% I want to increase maxnames here somehow:
% maxnames=10
\fullcite{A+04}
% and then I want to drop it again for the rest of the document. 
% maxnames=3

\section{In-text}
\citet{A+04} says interesting things.

\citet{A+02} says other things. 

\citet{A+03} disagree.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Typeset one citation with all authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142148/35864)

Comment: @moewe Thanks! I didn't spot that as I was trying to see if there was already a solution. :-\

Comment: Well, it's always easier to find the solution if you know what it looks like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a couple of ways:

1. You could make a command to set `maxcitenames`

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \newcommand{\setmaxcitenames}[1]{%
     \numdef\blx@maxcitenames{#1}}
   \makeatother
   ```

   Then use `\setmaxcitenames{10}` at the start of your section and `\setmaxcitenames{3}` at the end of your section.
2. You could make a new `\fullauthorcite` command

   ```
   \DeclareCiteCommand{\fullauthorcite}
     {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
     {\usedriver
        {\setcounter{maxnames}{10}% use up to 10 authors
         \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}
     {\multicitedelim}
     {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
   ```

   You could also redefine `\fullcite` like this.

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible idea. But I believe there is good chance that someone else will come up with something cleaner and better. Anyway, in the meantime, you could redefine `fullcite` in the section where you want to change `maxnames` and later restore it. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A+04,
  author = {Author, Aa and Buthor, Bb and Cuthor, Cc and Duthor, Dd},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal title},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {101--109},
  month = jan,
  note = {This is an article entry},
}
@article{A+02,
  author = {Author, Aa and Buthor, Bb},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal title},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {101--109},
  month = jan,
  note = {This is an article entry},
}
@article{A+03,
  author = {Author, Aa and Buthor, Bb and Cuthor, Cc},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal title},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {101--109},
  month = jan,
  note = {This is an article entry},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[bibstyle=alphabetic,maxnames=3,minnames=2,maxalphanames=1,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


\let\origfullcite\fullcite
\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{10}}}

\section{Fullcite}
% I want to increase maxnames here somehow:
% maxnames=10
\fullcite{A+04}
% and then I want to drop it again for the rest of the document. 
% maxnames=3

\let\fullcite\origfullcite

\section{In-text}
\citet{A+04} says interesting things.

\citet{A+02} says other things. 

\citet{A+03} disagree.

\fullcite{A+04}.
\end{document}
```