# \fullcite: Full list of authors

Tags: biblatex, citing

I need \fullcite to list all NOT authors BUT EDITORS of a book I am contributing to. Is thee way to force \fullcite to that, even the bibliography should not?

[image: Number_of_Eds_for_book]

In Addition to M. Quaresma the book has five other editors, all of whom I need listed.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sortlocale=danish,firstinits=true,style=authoryear-icomp,dashed=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=true]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifboolexpr{%
        test {\ifentrytype{article}}%
        or
        test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}%
    }{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite} %sets name order to last-first 
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usedriver
        {}
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: What about the other commands like `\cite`? Should they include the whole list of authors as well or only the first one (with et al) like in the bibliography?

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142148/typeset-one-citation-with-all-authors

Comment: @DavidPurton: Not really. Moewe's solution there solves a problem regarding the number of authors of the text cited. My problem is the number of editors of the book in which my paper is included. I'll add a picture to illustrate it.

Comment: Actually, you'll need `\newcommand{\tempmaxup}[1]{\def\blx@maxcitenames{99}#1}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on @moewe's solution from [Typeset one citation with all authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142148/typeset-one-citation-with-all-authors) you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,giveninits=true,maxnames=1]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tempmaxup}[1]{\def\blx@maxcitenames{99}#1}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}[\tempmaxup]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usedriver
        {}
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{coleridge}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]